# remove zero rows from numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Given m x n nd array of floats, what is the best way to get an m' x n nd array of floats that does not contain all-zero rows?

for example: Given

```
[ 
  [1.0, 0.0, 2.0], 
  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
  [2.0, 1.0, 0.0] 
]
```

I want to get

```
[ 
  [1.0, 0.0, 2.0], 
  [2.0, 1.0, 0.0] 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index using a boolean array:

```
a = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 2.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0, 0.0]])

print(a[a.any(axis=1)])
```

Here `a.any(axis=1)` will be `True` where any elements in the row are non-zero. These are the rows that we want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude those elements as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([ [1.0, 0.0, 2.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0, 0.0] ])
>>> x
array([[1., 0., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 1., 0.]])
>>> sumrow = np.abs(x).sum(-1)
>>> x[sumrow>0]
array([[1., 0., 2.],
       [2., 1., 0.]])
```

Note: @Akavall pointed out correctly that `np.abs()` would prevent issues with negative values.

Additionally, another more complex approach:

```
>>> x = np.array([ [1.0, 0.0, 2.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0, 0.0] ])
>>> x[~np.all(x == 0, axis=1)]
array([[1., 0., 2.],
       [2., 1., 0.]])
```

See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-indexing/

Comment: What if a row contains non zero elements that sum to 0, for example: `[-1.,  0.,  1.]`?

Comment: I suppose `np.abs(x).sum(-1)` will solve the issue that I pointed out.

Comment: You're correct @Akavall - I just edited the answer to be correct. Also added another approach.

Comment: Instead of `~np.all(x == 0, axis=1)` you can just do `x.any(axis=1)`. This saves some computation steps and temporary arrays, although by De Morgan's Laws we can see that it arrives at the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use the fact that the sum of all zeros is zero. Create a mask using that fact:

```
>>> bar = np.array ([ [1.0, 0.0, 2.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0, 0.0] ] )
>>> mask = bar.sum(axis=1)==0
>>> bar[mask]
array([[1., 0., 2.],
       [2., 1., 0.]])
```

Comment: O, that's actually the same answer as @Damiox gave :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import numpy as np
x    = np.array([ [1.0, 0.0, 2.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0, 0.0] ])
m, n = x.shape
rows = [row for row in range(m) if not all(x[row] == 0)]
x    = x[rows]
print(x)
```

This works for arrays containing negative data also. If we use sum suppose a row contains
[-1, 0, 1] it will be deleted we don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=np.array([r for r in a if any(r)])
```